# angular JS autocompelete directive using Jquery UI not working as expected in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Below is an Angular custom directive for auto complete using jquery-ui. It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and other browsers but in IE. I have even used

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

For compatibility issues. But here what actually is the problem is that when i type into the text box it shows auto complete options as expected. But when i selected one of the options the text in the textbox changes also the value of the textbox changes if you try accessing it using jquery/javascript. But the scope variable is not updated. In Chrome and firefox it gets updated as expected. But not in IE. Whatever i type is only reflected in the scope variable Can anyone help me understand the reason behind this issue and how to solve this.

```js
var App=angular.module('App',[]);
App.directive('complete', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.autocomplete({
            source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
            select: function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    iElement.trigger('input');
                }, 10);
            }
        });
    };
});
App.controller('HomeController', function($rootScope, $scope,  $timeout) {
 $scope.list = ['Python', 'MySQL', 'NodeJS', 'Oracle', 'PHP', 'AngularJS', 'Bootstrap',
       'C', 'C++', 'C#', 'CSS', 'HTML5', 'Java', 'JavaScript', 'jQuery', 'Perl', 'SQL', 'VB.NET',
       'ASP.NET', 'Unix', 'Shell Scripting', 'MSSQL', 'PL/SQL', 'CATIA', 'AutoCad', 'Visual Basic', 'Creo'];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>



<div ng-app="App">
  <div id="map" ng-controller="HomeController">
    <div>
  {{selectedItem}}
  </div>
  <input complete ui-items="list" ng-model="selectedItem"/>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle for the same Try this fiddle in IE to observe the issue

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vw67zmn/)**

Screenshots:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

change this `iElement.trigger('input');`

to this

```
iElement.trigger('change');
```

feature test for oninput support with ('input' in iElement)